# How to delay displaying 'next page' until it's fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my site's users to click a link within your site, have it display a progress bar at the top of page (like youtube) and it only displays the page which the user requested once it's fully loaded. How can I delay the loading of that next page?

Comment: Yes it quite possible.

Comment: Just for you: https://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLoadingEffects/